# Making a custom table with columns that are query results

Tags: django

What I want to achieve is to make load one of my django models into a table and add some columns where the additional columns are queries based on 2 of the cells in the row.
For example if the Person model has first name and last name, an additional column would be the result of "select top 1 from another_table where fname=fname and lname=lname"

I tried using django-tables2 and here is my code:

```
#models.py:
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    lname = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    age = models.IntegerField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s %s : %i' % (self.fname, self.lname, self.age)

class Map(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    info = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.person)

# views.py
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Person
from django_tables2   import RequestConfig
from .models  import Person
from .tables  import PersonTable

def people(request):
    table = PersonTable(Person.objects.all())
    RequestConfig(request).configure(table)
    return render(request, 'people.html', {'people': table})

#tables.py:
import django_tables2 as tables
from .models import Person

class PersonInfo(tables.Column):
    def render(self, value):
        return str(value) # <<====== this is later going to be my query

class PersonTable(tables.Table):
   info = PersonInfo()
   selection = tables.CheckBoxColumn(accessor="pk", orderable=False)

   class Meta:
       model = Person
```

There are 3 problems and any help is appreciated:

- I've sub-classed PersonInfo from the Column but the info values are blank.
- when made this sample app without the customized table, the table looked fine but now it is not showing the table border/formatting and also the browser indicates that screen.css was successfully loaded so I do not know why it looks like this.
- The checkboxes are successfully displayed but the do not have an id and they have identical names so how can I make them have distinct ids?

[image]

Comment: I might be missing the point, but why are you taking this approach at the 'backend'? How about you send the query results you want from whatever number of models, send them to the template, and over there, use template to tabulate your results appropriately?

Comment: You mean why not make the additional columns in the view...It's still backend. That would be good solution; however, I thought django-tables2 is made for facilitate this.

Comment: so that solution would solve the problem with the 'info' column. How about the checkboxes? If I have to make them in view.py, then there is no reason for using 'django-tables2'

Comment: Not in the views per se. Your goal is to have two columns or so, filled with data from two separate models, right? If so, let the views retrieve whatever the values you want from the two separate models and render to templates. In your templates *then* you, using standard {% for %} loop or appropriate means, structure your table with the data from both models.

Comment: What you described makes sense. djago-tables2 is not  useful to me then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is how I understand your question, and this is how I would go about it:

```
# models.py

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    age = models.IntergerField()

class Info(models.Model):
    the_person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    info = models.CharField(max_length=200)


# views.py
# I'm using Class Based Views from Generic Views

class PersonDetail(ListView):
    # automatically uses pk of 
    # model specified below as slug
    model = Person
```

So now in your template, you can have something like this:

```
# html. Just a rough html below. I hope it gives you the idea. Might not tabulate the data properly, but the point is is to have both model data in templates, then simply use {% for %} loop to list one data in one column or more columns of the table and then whatever model(s) in the other columns.
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Age</td> 
    <td>Info</td>
  </tr>
  {% for object in object_list %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ object.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ object.age }}</td> 
    {% for i in object.the_person.set_all %}
    <td>{{ i.info }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</table>
```

If you're looking to retrieve two models 'Non-ForeignKey-ed' to each other, you can use context object. [See here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview)

Comment: Thanks. This is interesting. Can you please explain whether object_list is a keyword or is just a variable name that you have to pass into  the template? How does it know what the object should be? I do have foreign keys but there are more than one table.

Comment: @max object_list is the default list generated which stores the objects retrieved from the model in context and is passed on to the templates to be handled by {% for %} loop or whatever. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#singleobjectmixin

Comment: @max It knows what the object should be based on the arg or kwarg passed to it. By default, the PersonDetail Class above will query the Person Model using the pk value caught in your url. At this point, I'll recommend you thoroughly read the Django documentation. Your questions are all in the documentation. Read, re-read, re-re-read if you're new to Django.

Comment: Thanks. I've accepted this as an answer without testing it since this approach will not be flexible enough for what I really want to do.

Comment: Sorry it doesn't meet your needs precisely. I hope you let us know how you work around eventually